# How to mock python's read()

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to test the `read()` method in the following class:

```
class Channel(sam.Sam):
  def __open(self):
    try:
      self.__channel = open('%s/channel.ini' % os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'r+')
    except Exception as e:
      traceback.print_exc(file = sys.stdout)
      raise e

  def read(self):
    try:
      self.__open()
      return JSONEncoder().encode({
        "status": True,
        "channel": self.__channel.read().strip()
      })
    except Exception as e:
      traceback.print_exc(file = sys.stdout)
      return JSONEncoder().encode({
        "status": False
      })
    finally:
      self.__close()
```

As I understand it, I should be mocking the `file.read()` method (in `self.__channel.read()`, or maybe the `os.open()` method, but none of the examples I've found have the call to `os.open()` or `file.read()` deep inside a class.

I already tried `__builtin__.read = MagicMock(return_value="something")`, and many variations thereof, but not one of them even make sense. I'm kind of lost as to how to even start this.

Is this even the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mock the `open` function; you can use the [`mock_open()` utility function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open) to provide a suitable mock:

```
from unittest.mock import mock_open

with patch('your_module.open', mock_open(read_data=JSON_TEST_DATA), create=True) as m:
    result = Channel().read()
    assert m.assert_called_once_with(expected_file_name)
```

The `patch()` call creates a new global `open` object in your `your_module` namespace, so when the `Channel.__open()` method runs it'll find *that* object rather than the `open()` built-in function.

By passing in a `read_data` argument to `mock_open()`, you can dictate what is returned by the `self.__channel.read()` call.